# Make Recursive Function Return a Tuple

Tags: python, function, recursion, tuples

I want the following function to return a tuple for every year ie. if its 5 years it will give me a tuple of year1, year2, year3, year4, year5.

```
def nextSalaryFixed(salary, percentage, growth, years):
if years == 1:
        tup = (salary * (percentage * 0.01), )
        return tup[years-1]
    else:
        tup = (nextEggFixed(salary, percentage, growth, years - 1) * ((1 + (0.01 * growth))) + (salary * (percentage * 0.01)))
        print(tup)
        return tup
```

Comment: `nextEggFixed`? what is that defined as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []

def nextSalaryFixed(salary, percentage, growth, years):
    if years == 1:
        tup = salary * (percentage * 0.01)
    else:
        tup = (nextSalaryFixed(salary, percentage, growth, years - 1) *
            ((1 + (0.01 * growth))) + (salary * (percentage * 0.01)))

    result.append((years, tup))
    return tup

nextSalaryFixed(10000, 10, 5, 5)
result # [(1, 1000.0), (2, 2050.0), (3, 3152.5), (4, 4310.125), (5, 5525.63125)]
```